# in c programming , adding function with #pragma omp parallel for, cause other variable to be changed

Tags: c, openmp

hi i have struct which contains a string in c. i malloc memory for string and when i printf its value it is empty as i expect.

after adding new function which uses open mp tag (#pragma omp parallel for) above of a dummy loop, value of my string changes.

how can i stop changing of my string value?
whats the reason of this behavior?

here is my code and output before adding function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define RESULT_LENGTH 100000

struct SimpleSearch {

    char* ids;
};

int main () {

   struct SimpleSearch search;
   search.ids = malloc((RESULT_LENGTH) * sizeof(char));
 
   printf("search id now is: %s\n",search.ids);

   return 0;

}
```

output is:

```
search id now is:
```

then i add new function and complete code will be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omp.h>



#define RESULT_LENGTH 100000

struct SimpleSearch {

    char* ids;
};

void x(){
    #pragma omp parallel for 
     for(int i=0; i <(10+1); i++) {
        printf("%d \n",i);
     }
}
 
int main () {

   struct SimpleSearch search;
   search.ids = malloc((RESULT_LENGTH) * sizeof(char));
 
   printf("search id now is: %s\n",search.ids);

   return 0;

}
```

now ouput will be:

```
search id now is: ���
```

Comment: `search.ids` gets assigned some random memory location. This memory location is never initialized to a meaningful value.

Comment: so what should i do . because in my real code i will sprintf to ids and these characters stay at the first of ids string.  
@Raildex

Comment: here is my code:
`sprintf(search->ids+ strlen(search->ids), "%s,",seprated_keys_id[0]);`
 @Raildex

Comment: Undefined behaviour stay undefined behaviour, the cause is not adding omp function, adding something else could change the undefined behaviour due to using uninitialized memory.

Comment: thank you so much. i learned many things.
then for initializing i can use 2 way:

`search.ids[RESULT_LENGTH];`

or
`search.ids =malloc((RESULT_LENGTH) * sizeof(char));
   search.ids = calloc(RESULT_LENGTH, sizeof(char));`

Comment: Use `search.ids[0]='\0';` to set it to an empty string.